# Eclipse trying to migrate project to Worklight 6.1.0.01 instead of 6.0.0.2

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Worklight 6.0 with Eclipse, recently I applied Fix Patch 2 Studio version manually, since I did not want to upgrade to 6.1,

> Now technically my Eclipse should be on 6.0.0.2 , however when I try
>   to open a project, eclipse automatically tries Migrating the project
>   to 6.1 from 6.0.

Anyone has faced a similar issue?

P.S. I can still see IBM Worklight Studio version 6.1.0.01 as an available Update in my Eclipse.

Comment: Are you sure that your eclipse has only one version of IBM Worklight? Just check in Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details ( if it is  Windows PC ) to check installed Worklight

Comment: I have two entries for Worklight Studio, and both of them are of 6.0 versions (6.0.0.201309262019 and 6.0.0.201402081712)

Yes it is a Windows PC

Comment: it is not the same version. AFAIK it has different fix pack i guess. You can see that in the last digits. one is 201309262019 another one is 201402081712. Generally it means the release date of worklight fix pack. for example 2014-02-08-17:12. So try to uninstall the 6.0.0.201309262019 version from Eclipse and try once.

Comment: Oh I was under impression that it would be as a top up, let me try, I think you are right.

Comment: I have uninstalled the Extra Version, but the problem is still there.

Now my eclipse has only ONE version listed in installed software list.

Comment: Some time back i had the same issues while upgrading to 6.0.0.2 manually. eclipse will take a back up ( zip ) of my old project and it tried to migrate. I un installed all the Worklight from eclipse,installed only the fix pack then created a new workspace , project and copied my old code to new one. Now it is working fine

Comment: @Bluewings yes exactly the same I have been facing. 

Tried your solution, migration succeeded, however it is still saying Migrating to version 6.1 . Is it same with you too ?

Comment: For me it is working fine. am using old code only from my SVN. Try to get new eclipse and install 6.0.0.2 and try.

Comment: As Bluewings states above, please start with a fresh eclipse and install 6.0.0.2. Please let us know the outcome

Comment: @Bluewings the solution worked, if you could change the comment as answer, I can mark it. 

I do not know why, but it turns out to be the only solution, Remove Eclipse, re-install eclipse, use a new workspace, install worklight 6.0.0.2 and import the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround to solve this problem you can

- Remove the current eclipse
- Install new Eclipse
- Create a new Workspace
- Install the IBM worklight 6.0.0.2 Plugins to eclipse
- Import your old project